# How to get for to stand separate in an equation?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    C_k = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N k_n           for k \in {1,\dots,K}
\end{equation}
```

How can I get the for, and everything after it, to stand 'separate' from the equation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\quad` to add a space (or `\qquad` if you want it bigger) and `\text{}` to insert some text in your equation in a way that it is not typeset in `displaymath` style. Remember also to insert a space right after the text with`\` or to add it inside the text like `\text{for }`.

```
\begin{equation}
    C_k = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N k_n \quad \text{for}\  k \in \{1,\dots,K\}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd go “all the way”: `\text{for $k\in\{1,\dots,K\}$}` so you don't risk forgetting spaces. I'd also add a comma after the main part of the formula (but this is only personal preference). I'd also suppress “for”, probably.

Comment: @egreg never thought of using this solution.. nice!

Comment: In this case it's not so important, as there is only one space to take care of. In other cases it can be much handier.

Comment: I would use `\qquad` to get a more visual separation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to do this

```
\newcommand\qqtext{\qquad\text}
\begin{equation}
    C_k = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N k_n   \qqtext{for $k \in {1,\dots,K}$}
\end{equation}
```

Note that I include the entire `for...` part inside the `\qqtext{...}`, because semantically this is where it belongs.

This way I ensure I always have the same distance for the *conditions*. I also tend to use the following macros

```
\newcommand\qtextq[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad} % for 'and' between eqs
\newcommand\qtext{\quad\text}  % when there is not enough space for \qqtext
```

Plus possibly `e` versions using `\enspace` instead of `\quad`.

I tend to hide these spacings inside macros in order to make the general text easier to read (less typographic noise).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `align` environment for this, this is especially useful if there's more than one line and you want all of them to be aligned the same way. The `&` specifies where to align.

```
\begin{align}
    C_k &= \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N k_n & &\text{for}\ k \in {1,\dots,K}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Using an `align` structure for the purpose at hand is borderline overkill. Using `align` for a single-line equation can also create inferior vertical spacing compared with an environment such as `equation`.